# Is it possible to add a Mobile Service to Windows Azure Subscription programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-management

I want to be able to add a mobile service to my Windows Azure subscription from code. Just the creation and not the actual publishing of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but the Azure documentation explains how to use the Azure CLI and PowerShell to create a new Mobile Service:

```
azure mobile create "service-name" "server-admin" "server-password
```

Check the documentation for step-by-step inscructions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-manage-command-line-interface/

Comment: Holy crap, you are my new favorite person